# Adding login/password credentials to Stackoverflow account

Tags: support, bug, login

Is there a way to add plain login/password credentials to my Stackoverflow account? In the My Logins page (/users/login-add) I can only add new Google and Facebook logins. There is no option to add plain login/password login however Stackoverflow allows to register new accounts without OpenID provider.